# Issues that im having is when I grab one key than go to the next it only show that I grab one key at a time in which I need it to show all grab keys

Tags: wpf, vb.net

```
Class MainWindow
    
    'declare strings
    Dim message As String = ""
    Dim currentRoomName As String
    
    'declare dictionaries
    Dim start, grassland, underground, sky, castle, beach, underwater, volcano As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim currentRoom As Dictionary(Of String, String)
    
    'declare list
    Dim gameIteams As New List(Of String)

    'declare key true/false 
    Dim key As Boolean = False

    Private Sub btnGrab__Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnGrab_.Click
        If currentRoomName = "sky" Then
            gameIteams.Add("key")
            key = True
            lbllnfo.Content = "You have the first key"
            lstltems.ItemsSource = gameIteams
        ElseIf currentRoomName = "underground" Then
            gameIteams.Add("key2")
            key = True
            lbllnfo.Content = "You have the Second key"
            lstltems.ItemsSource = gameIteams
        ElseIf currentRoomName = "volcano" Then
            gameIteams.Add("key3")
            key = True
            lbllnfo.Content = "You have the third key"
            lstltems.ItemsSource = gameIteams
        Else
                lbllnfo.Content = "Nothing here"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image: listbox]

try to name each key but still only showing one each click I need the list to show every key when pick up..

Comment: There I just add the code the last pic just to show that only one key will show

Comment: Where is the value of currentRoomName being set?  Also be aware that String comparisons such as this are case sensitive.   Also not sure you need to be resetting lstltems.ItemsSource on each case, maybe just refresh the data, maybe instead of that, you need to clear the listbox first before resetting the itemsource

Answer (score 0):

it is not easy to understand what you mean. But maybe this code works for you:

```
Dim CurrentRoomName As String = ""
Dim GameItems As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

Private Sub BtnGrap_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnGrap.Click
    LblInfo.Text = "Nothing here"
    Select Case CurrentRoomName
        Case "sky"
            If Not GameItems.ContainsKey("key1") Then
                GameItems.Add("key1", "You have the first key")
            End If
            ShowKeys()
        Case "underground"
            If Not GameItems.ContainsKey("key2") Then
                GameItems.Add("key2", "You have the second key")
            End If
            ShowKeys()
        Case "volcano"
            If Not GameItems.ContainsKey("key3") Then
                GameItems.Add("key3", "You have the third key")
            End If
            ShowKeys()
    End Select
End Sub
Private Sub ShowKeys()
    If GameItems.Count > 0 Then
        LblInfo.Text = ""
        For Each Vp As KeyValuePair(Of String, String) In GameItems
            LblInfo.Text &= IIf(LblInfo.Text <> "", vbCrLf, "") & Vp.Value
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```